# Make a navigation bar retain position when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this question has been asked before, but I'm pretty sure after checking them out, that none of the navigation bars where built like this one.

I'm basically having trouble making the navigation bar "seamlessly" switch to a fixed position at the top of the screen after scrolling past its original position, then back again.

I have included the code, and an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/r2a6U/

Here is the actual function which makes the div switch to fixed position mode:

```
var navPos = $('#navContainer').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var fixIT = $(this).scrollTop() >= navPos;

  var setPos = fixIT ? 'fixed' : 'relative' ;
  var setTop = fixIT ? '0' : '600' ;

  $('#navContainer').css({position: setPos});
  $('#navContainer').css({'top': setTop});

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your issue to remove the styles instead of setting them to `relative` and `600px`. I suggest you add/remove a class in JavaScript which will then apply the fixed CSS though. You will end up with much nicer and cleaner JavaScript.

Also make sure you center `#navContainer` properly when it's fixed.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/RKzVD/1/)

**CSS**

```
#navContainer.fixIT {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;

    /* these will ensure it is centered so it doesn't jump to the side*/
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**JS**

```
var navPos = $('#navContainer').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fixIT = $(this).scrollTop() >= navPos;

    if (fixIT)
        $('#navContainer').addClass('fixIT');
    else
        $('#navContainer').removeClass('fixIT');
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank-you very much sir. I was struggling with this one for a while! This also gave me some extra knowledge on jQuery which may be of use in the future!

Comment: Nps, whenever I find myself wanting to use `.css()` in jQuery I normally do it using a class. Don't forget to hit the tick to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Fix it in here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2a6U/1/)

Only a small script update:

> var navPos = $('#navContainer').offset().top;
>
> $(window).scroll(function(){
>           var navContainer = $('#navContainer');
>
> ```
>     if( $(this).scrollTop() >= navPos ) {
>         // make it fixed to the top
>         $('#navContainer').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 0 });
>     } else {
>         // restore to orignal position
>         $('#navContainer').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top': 600 });
>     }
> });
> ```